# Can I suppress the implicit timeout without having a WebDriver object?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

The [WebDriver API](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements%28org.openqa.selenium.By%29) says to use `findElements` to check for the existence or non-existence of a `WebElement`. This method is subject to the implicit timeout value. Thus if I want to write a method to check for existence, and I don't want the method to wait for the implicit timeout, I can suppress it temporarily like this:

```
protected boolean doesElementExist(By by) {
    // Temporarily set the implicit timeout to zero
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    // Check to see if there are any elements in the found list
    boolean exists = driver.findElements(by).size() > 0;
    // Return to the original implicit timeout value
    driver.manage().timeouts()
            .implicitlyWait(Properties.TIMEOUT_TEST, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return exists;
}
```

But this requires that you have the `WebDriver` to manage the timeout value. I am currently moving methods like the one above into a custom subclass of `By` called `Locator` so that I can call these methods from the driver or from a specific `WebElement`, and also so that I can extend the `Locator` with regular expression matching and other forms of information retrieval.

The problem is that within my `Locator` class, I don't have the `WebDriver`, I have the `SearchContext`. I imagine there ought to be a way to alter the timeout - or to call something like `findElements` with a custom timeout - from within the context of a `WebElement`. Is there such a way? Or do I have to suppress the timeout value in my implementation of these methods in my custom `WebDriver` and `WebElement` implementations (which have also been extended in order to make these new methods available to them)? Thanks!

Comment: Why not you have the web driver?

Comment: Methods like `findElements` are actually part of the `By` class. `WebDriver` and `WebElement` both implement the `SearchContext` interface which contains `findElement`(s) methods that essentially call the `By` methods using themselves as the `SearchContext` (this way the root of the search is either the whole DOM or a specific `WebElement` depending on what you call it off of). So I'm adding this method to a subclass of `By`, which doesn't have any direct access to the `WebDriver` being used.

Comment: Generally don't use implicit waits, only use explicit ones, that will prevent you hitting this problem.